# Automate creating configurations from template and excel

Tags: excel, powershell, networking, automation

I'm having trouble in automation of a configuration.
I have a template of a configuration and need to change all the hostname (marked as YYY) and IP (marked as XXX(only 3rd octet needs replacement)) according to a list of excel values.
Now I have a list of 100 different sites and IPs and I want to have also 100 different configurations.

A friend suggested to use the following Powershell code but it doesn't any create files..:

```
    $replaceValues = Import-Csv -Path "\\ExcelFile.csv"
    $file = "\\Template.txt"
    $contents = Get-Content -Path $file
    
    foreach ($replaceValue in $replaceValues) 
    {    
            $contents = $contents -replace "YYY", $replaceValue.hostname
            $contents = $contents -replace "XXX", $replaceValue.site
        Copy-Item $file "$($file.$replaceValue.hostname)"
        Set-Content -Path "$($file.$replaceValue.hostname)" -Value $contents
        echo "$($file.$replaceValue.hostname)"
     }
```

Comment: \\excelfile.CSV’ and ‘\\template.txt’ are not valid file paths first off

Comment: The files are on a network share so just go with it, is the code supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to overwrite the same `$contents` string in the loop, so if the values are replaced the first time you enter the loop, there won't be any `YYY` or `XXX` values to replace left..
You need to keep the **template text** intact, and create a new copy from the template inside the loop. That copy can then be altered the way you want. Every next iteration wil then start off with a fresh copy of the template.

There is no need to first copy the template text to a new location and then overwrite this file with the new contents. `Set-Content` is happy to create a new file for you if it does not already exist.

Try

```
$replaceValues = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\Values.csv'
$template      = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\Template.txt'

foreach ($item in $replaceValues) {  
    $content = $template -replace 'YYY', $item.hostname -replace 'XXX', $item.site
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path 'D:\Test' -ChildPath ('{0}.txt' -f $item.hostname)
    Write-Host "Creating file '$newFile'"
    $content | Set-Content -Path $newFile
}
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you very much ! It actually worked, But the files are missing an extension, what do I need to add to get .txt files ?

Comment: And btw how does PS know what exactly is $item ? does it mean a cell in excel ?

Comment: @EliLevitan I have edited so the file now gets a `.txt` extension. `$item` is the variable used to iterate each **object** in the array (got from the **rows** in the csv file)